# SQL Select Distinct Records From Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, multiple-tables, full-outer-join

I am trying to write a SQL statement that will return a set of Distinct set of CompanyNames from a table based on the most recent SaleDate withing a specified date range from another table.
T01 = Account
T02 = TransHeader

The fields of importance are:
T01.ID, T01.CompanyName
T02.AccountID, T02.SaleDate

T01.ID = T02.AccountID

What I want to return is the Max SaleDate for each CompanyName without any duplicate CompanyNames and only the Max(SaleDate) as LastSale.  I will be using a Where Clause to limit the SaleDate range.

I tried the following but it returns all the records for all SalesDates in the range. This results in the same company being listed multiple times.

**Current MS-SQL Query**

```
SELECT T01.CompanyName, T02.LastSale
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT ID, IsActive, ClassTypeID, CompanyName FROM Account) T01
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT AccountID, TransactionType, MAX(SaleDate) LastSale FROM TransHeader group by AccountID, TransactionType, SaleDate) T02
    ON T01.ID = T02.AccountID
WHERE ( ( T01.IsActive = 1 )AND 
        ( (Select Max(SaleDate)From TransHeader Where AccountID = T01.ID AND TransactionType in (1,6) AND SaleDate is NOT NULL) 
            BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '12/31/2018 23:59:00' AND (Select Max(SaleDate)From TransHeader Where AccountID = T01.ID AND TransactionType in (1,6) AND SaleDate is NOT NULL) IS NOT NULL
        ) 
      )
ORDER BY T01.CompanyName
```

I thought the FULL OUTER JOIN was the ticket but it did not work and I am stuck.

Sample data **Account** Table (T01)

```
ID     CompanyName   IsActive   ClassTypeID
1      ABC123        1          1
2      CDE456        1          1
3      EFG789        1          1
4      Test123       0          1
5      Test456       1          1
6      Test789       0          1
```

Sample data **Transheader** table (T02)

```
AccountID  TransactionType  SaleDate
1          1                02/03/2012
2          1                03/04/2013 
3          1                04/05/2014
4          1                05/06/2014
5          1                06/07/2014  
6          1                07/08/2015 
1          1                08/09/2016
1          1                01/15/2016
2          1                03/20/2017
2          1                03/21/2017 
3          1                03/04/2017
3          1                04/05/2018
3          1                05/27/2018
4          1                06/01/2018
5          1                07/08/2018 
5          1                08/01/2018
5          1                10/11/2018
6          1                11/30/2018
```

**Desired Results**

```
CompanyName     LastSale    (Notes note returned in the result)
ABC123          01/15/2016  (Max(SaleDate) LastSale for ID=1)
CDE456          03/21/2017  (Max(SaleDate) LastSale for ID=2)
EFG789          05/27/2018  (Max(SaleDate) LastSale for ID=3)
Testing456      10/11/2018  (Max(SaleDate) LastSale for ID=5)

ID=4 & ID=6 are note returned because IsActive = 0 for these records.
```

Comment: Hi @CainGoettelman, I assume that this last 4 rows of data is the desired result you want to get with the query. Can you give us some example data from which you will get that results (if you have 30 rows just show us 6 of them that will explain the situation). Also please can you tag the database you are using (Is it Oracle or MySQL or something else ?) Welcome to Stack Overflow. Cheers!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your question is inconsistent.  The first paragraph says you want four columns.  The second says you want two.  The query has a date range, but the question doesn't.  I would suggest you delete this question.  Then ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.  As you both suggested that sample data would be helpful I will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to select the maximum date in the select clause.

```
select
  a.*,
  (
    select max(th.saledate)
    from transheader th
    where th.accountid = a.id
    and th.saledate >= '2016-01-01'
    and th.saledate < '2019-01-01'
  ) as max_date
from account a
where a.isactive = 1
order by a.id;
```

If you only want to show transaction headers with sales dates in the given date range, then you can just inner join the maximum dates with the accounts. In order to do so, you must group your date aggregation per account:

```
select a.*, th.max_date
from account a
join
(
  select accountid, max(saledate) as max_date
  from transheader
  and saledate >= '2016-01-01'
  and saledate < '2019-01-01'
  group by accountid
) th on th.accountid = a.id
where a.isactive = 1
order by a.id;
```

Comment: This gets me closer.  The issue now is this query returns NULL SalesDates.  I attempted to add and additional where condition:

and th.saledate IS NOT NULL

but this did not remove the Null SaleDates from the returned records.
Thoughts?

Comment: Oh, I though that you had problems writing the query, because you *wanted* to get the accounts even when there were no matching dates. Especially as you mentioned outer joins. If you only want matches, then you can just inner join. (The same would have been possible with my first query in `select * from (<query>) where max_date is not null order by id`, but an inner join is the typical way to go here.) I've added the according query to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CompanyName,MAX(SaleDate) SaleDate from Account a
inner join Transheader b on a.id = b.accountid
group by CompanyName
order by 1
```

Comment: what type of more information you want to add ?? @hotfix

Comment: just a code snippet is not a good answer. an answer should also be explained so that everyone can understand it. Have a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)